# How to prevent developers from deleting perforce depot?

Tags: permissions, perforce

I am a newbie to perforce and recently started experimenting. I am normal developer with write privileges and  was able to delete the entire depot. How can i avoid this while retaining write privileges? 
Is there any other way other than Trigger and permission table?

Also, if the developer has deleted a [depot? -msw]  and submitted the changelist, how to recover during the following scenarios:

1. Checkpoint and journal have not been created?
2. Workspace synced to the depot, and has cleared the workspace eventually.

But the developer is able to view files through the changelist. [??? -msw]

I request someone to clear-up these things for me.

Comment: Checkpoint, and journal management is another un-related question about Perforce backup. That you'll have to address later anyway...

Comment: @msw there is no requirement for you to label your edits (infact it just confuses things, I thought the user had issued a depot? -msw command).  If someone is interested in what you have changed they can check the versioning.

Comment: @toby: acknowledged, I was trying to make the OP make sense but there were bits where I had to guess; regardless you make a great point and I shan't introduce such confusion again.

Answer (score 9):

If you give a user write privileges to a directory in Perforce, there is no way to prevent them from deleting it.  You can mitigate the damage they can do by narrowing their permissions.  Only give them access to what they need, rather than the entire depot.

When you delete files in Perforce, they are not gone, they are just hidden.  You can display them with the "Show Deleted Depot Files" option on the filter menu.

[image]

They can easily be restored using the ["Rollback..." or "Back Out Submitted Changelist *N*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775823/what-is-the-difference-between-rollback-and-back-out-submitted-changelist) options.

[image]

Files are only truly gone when you use the *obliterate* command, to which only super users have access.