# Perforce: How can I back out a changelist across an integration?

Tags: version-control, branch, perforce, perforce-integrate

At my company we make a new branch/folder for every release. In the 1.0 folder, there is a changelist that introduced a bug. Unfortunately, 1.0 is shipped and we are working on 2.0. How can I take the changes in the 1.0 changelist and revert them only in the 2.0 folder?

I can think of the following solution.

1. Back out that revision in 1.0
2. Submit it
3. Integrate between 1.0 and 2.0 to apply the changes made by backing out.

However, the 1.0 branch should be locked since it is shipped. Can I do this without submitting a changelist to 1.0?

Comment: I faced similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962967/perforce-removing-delta-per-given-changelist-range Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create the necessary changelist on the 1.0 branch without submitting it, and then integrate to HEAD in your 2.0 branch and apply it there. [Instructions here.](http://kb.perforce.com/article/14#old)

Comment: Thanks, your link only contains instructions for how to back out a changelist normally though. I need to be able to back out of the changelist and integrate that deleted changelist to 2.0 without submitting the backed out changes to 1.0.

Comment: I don't think that solving my problem the way I want it solved is possible, so I marked you as the correct answer. I guess I will have to commit the backed out revision to 1.0, integrate to 2.0, then revert the 1.0 change.